# How to click Logout as finalizer in CasperJS

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am creating a web scraper (in CasperJS using JavaScript) that needs login authentication. However I need it to **click logout link in the end of script even when the process throws error**, such as non-existent element which might occurs frequently while in trial-and-error development. The behavior is similar to Java's `finally {}` block.

This behavior is required since the web allows only single session per user. If I don't click the logout, the next scraper invocation must wait 5 minutes to expire the previous session which is not good.

Where should I put the logout click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`casper.options.exitOnError`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#exitonerror) property to false to let the script continue to execute which will eventually execute your logout click.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    exitOnError: false,
});
```

or

```
casper.options.exitOnError = false;
```

This only works in with PhantomJS 1.x, because PhantomJS 2 doesn't throw an error when a selector cannot be found. CasperJS simply stops in this case.